# UI for making chessboards

Tags: feature-request, pgn-viewer

You can make chessboards in markdown, but it's hard to type, difficult for beginners to understand, and it's not visual representation of the end result at all. How about we have a UI for making chessboards just like Stack Snippets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be hard to type, but it is a worldwide [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation), and most (commercial) chess programs support the FEN notation, so you can easily import/export positions from and to Stack Exchange.

I agree that it would be nice to have a graphical editor, but I fear that it is a lot of work and won't be done by Stack Exchange developers for just a small site like this one. Maybe if somebody from the community developed a JavaScript editor, they could include it, and if not, then it might work as a user script.